# Spring batch is getting stopped while updating more than 1000 records through itemwriter class

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I'm using Spring batch to read and update same DB table through JPAPagingItemReader and customized Itemwriter class using Open JPA.

But, while trying to update more than 1000 records, some of the records are not updated and batch is getting stopped with either of batch statuses STOPPED, FAILED, UNKNOWN (with no Exceptions during batch process)

The below is what I'm doing in my code

**1) Reader -**

```
<beans:bean id="dataReader"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader" scope="step">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <beans:property name="pageSize" value="1"/>
    <beans:property name="queryString"
    value="select b from Test b where b.testStatus = #{jobParameters[status]}"/>  <!—here status value is ‘No’ -->
</beans:bean>
```

**2) Processor –**
Doing some business logic depends on some condition

**3) Writer –**

```
<beans:bean id="dataWriter"
class="com.example.batch..DataWriter">
    <beans:property name="entityManager" ref="sharedEntityManager" />
</beans:bean>
```

---

```
public class DataWriter implements ItemWriter<TestData> {
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return this.entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void write  (List<? extends TestData> items) {
        try {
            for (TestData testData : items) {
                updateTestDataStatus(testData.getTestDataKey());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updateTestDataStatus(String testDataKey) {
        Test test = getEntityManager().find(Test.class, testDataKey); //getEntityManager is sharedEntityManager
        test.setTestStatus("Yes");  
        getEntityManager().persist(test);
    }
}
```

**4) DB config**

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<beans:bean id="sharedEntityManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Configuration for JPATransaction Manager -->
<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Configuration for EntityManager -->
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testdata-pu" />
    <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans:property name="databasePlatform"
                value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary" />
            <beans:property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
            <beans:property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Configuration for Data Source -->
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSourcePropertiesplaceholder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
    <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:datasource.properties"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- jobRepository - in-memory mapping configuration -->
<beans:bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="transactionManager" ref="jobRepository-transactionManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jobRepository-transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
```

Comment: Every thing looks fine - are you really using it -- **<beans:property name="pageSize" value="1"/>** Please share your job and step level configurations - Are you also using - Skip Limit and if yes what is the limit that you have set - To track the skipped and failed record - you can add listeners over writer - and you can logg failures using onWriteError method . Looking forward to see the job level config -

Comment: `<beans:bean id="jobLauncher"
  class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
  <beans:property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
 </beans:bean>
 
 <job id="testDataJob" job-repository="jobRepository" restartable="true">
  <step id="step1">
   <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <chunk commit-interval="1" reader="dataReader"
     processor="dataProcessor" writer="dataWriter">
    </chunk>
   </tasklet>
  </step>
 </job>`

Comment: I'm not using any skip limit.

Comment: cant tell why it is failing while trying to update more than 1000 records ,  but for some of the records which are not updated you can track them by logger implementation in listeners ,

Comment: writerListener and StepListener might help u in finding out the root cause

Comment: But, I'm not getting any exception during the process.

Comment: try adding skip limit and set it to zero - then u might get the exceptions

Comment: Thank you. Sure will try with it.

Comment: you may also get counts in stepExecutionListener such as  -- read count , write count , commit count , skip count -